# How to substring a String containing 4 bytes characters?

Tags: java, string, unicode, utf-16, codepoint

I have a String that could contain 4 bytes characters. For example:

`String s = "\uD83D\uDC4D1234\uD83D\uDC4D";`

I also have a size that I should use to get a substring from it. The size is in characters. So let's say that size is 5, so I should get the first 4 bytes character along with "1234".

Directly using substring as `s.substring(0, 5)` gives the wrong result returning the first character and just "123".

I could manage to get the right result using code points this way:

```
String s = "\uD83D\uDC4D1234\uD83D\uDC4D";
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
long size = 5;
s.codePoints().forEachOrdered(charInt -> {
    if(buf.codePoints().count() < size) {
        buf.appendCodePoint(charInt);
    }
});
```

I bet there should be a way better and more efficient code to achieve this.

Comment: I don't understand. Characters in Java are two bytes. `substring` interprets characters, not codepoints (nor graphemes).  .

Comment: You want the thumbs up and 1234 as your result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`offsetByCodePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#offsetByCodePoints-int-int-) in order to help find the index of the character following 5 code points, and then use that as the second parameter to `substring`:

```
String s = "\uD83D\uDC4D1234\uD83D\uDC4D";
String sub = s.substring(0, s.offsetByCodePoints(0, 5));
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/uoWIK2)

Comment: That's worked perfect. Thanks!